# Chrome on iOS not rendering button properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, google-chrome

I have a front-end component for a project that's exhibiting the following bug:

There's a button at the bottom of the screen of one of my Panes and ONLY on chrome on iOS does the button not show.  If I tap the address bar, then the button appears presumably because the pane has redrawn itself.

The other problem is that I can't recreate the bug.  It only appears on a client's web app.  Things that could be super helpful:

- what's a good way to inspect Chrome on iOS? (I know how to inspect Safari on iOS, Chrome on Android, but not Chrome on iOS.  I've also already tried the devtools mobile emulator and it does not reproduce there)
- any related posts for bugs on Chrome on iOS (I've done some search already but if anyone has something deep in the internet that they remember)
- any knowledge of how Chrome renders things differently than Safari for iPhones
- any ideas on intermediate solutions
- any ideas on potential causes

Comment: I would post this question on Super User. If you are looking for a way to inspect Chrome iOS, go to chrome and hit inspect. Then change the device to iPhone.

Comment: well it depends on the CSS that you are using. What is the exact issue and the CSS that you are using. Elaborate more in details.

if you need to check cross mobile compatibility use emulator like browserstack to inspect and check the issue.